# How to ignore VALUES in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

Part of my query looks something like this:

```
  GRAPH g1: {VALUES (?ut) {$U1}
        ?IC_uri skos:related ?ut .
    }
```

Normally, based on user input, `$U1` gets a list of URIs. I would like to send for test purposes values for `$U1` so that the declaration of values is ignored and all possible values are considered. In fact, it should produce the same results as:

```
  GRAPH g1: {
        # VALUES (?ut) {$U1}
        ?IC_uri skos:related ?ut .
    }
```

I remember there  was a way to do that, but I couldn't find it in the SPARQL specification.

Comment: Ignore what exactly? Some of the values of the `VALUES` clause? Sure, you could comment a line via `#`. Besides this, SPARQL has only `MINUS`, `FILTER( NOT IN (...))`, `FILTER NOT EXISTS {...}`, to do some kind of negation. Anything else is beyond SPARQL specs afaik.

Comment: Hm, try to pass `UNDEF`...

Comment: @StanislavKralin It works! Thanks a lot. Please put it as an answer so that people can benefit from that. I'm currently not able to test it on another platform to be sure if it's not implementation-specific (in relation to the AKSW comment) but it's a valuable knowledge anyway.

Comment: @AKSW , I just checked and it is in the SPARQL specs: "If a variable has no value for a particular solution in the VALUES clause, the keyword UNDEF is used instead of an RDF term."

Comment: Ok, I didn't know what exactly you meant by "ignore" - just for my understanding, what's the difference compared to omitting the whole `VALUES` part w.r.t. to your example? For n-tuples, ok, you could omit parts of a tuple, e.g. `VALUE (?a ?b) {(UNDEF <x> )}`

Comment: @AKSW the query is behind a URL re-write rule. The client application cannot omit the `VALUES` as it simply has no access to the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose three options:

- `FILTER (?ut IN ($ut))`, passing `$ut` instead of a list of URIs;
- `BIND ($ut as ?ut)`, passing `$ut` instead of a single URI;
- `VALUES (?ut) {(UNDEF)}`, passing `(UNDEF)` instead of a space-separated list of (parentheses-enclosed) URIs.

Such SPARQL injections can not be considered safe.

The `UNDEF` keyword first mentioned in [10.2.2 VALUES Examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data-examples):

> If a variable has no value for a particular solution in the `VALUES` clause, the keyword `UNDEF` is used instead of an RDF term.

Comment: It's not a space-separated list of URI, and for that reason, I'm using ()-syntax. I'm using URL rewrite rules to keep the control at the server side. So the request is http://{source pattern}/{$U1}, that's why a list for A, B, C URI has no spaces: http://{source pattern}/(A)(B)(C)